# Convert dnspython dns.resolver.Answer object to raw bytes reply

Tags: python, dns

I used dnspython to make a query to a DNS server and get a response; my response came in the form of a `dns.resolver.Answer` object.
I would like to forward this DNS reply somewhere else using python sockets, and to do that I need the raw form of this message, that looks like this:

```
b'\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x10googletagmanager\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01'
```

I used the documentation and `.__dict__` and found `dns.resolver.Answer` contained:

```
{'qname': <DNS name www.example.com.>, 'rdtype': <RdataType.A: 1>, 'rdclass': <RdataClass.IN: 1>, 'response': <DNS message, ID 1111>, 'nameserver': '8.8.8.8', 'port': 53, 'canonical_name': <DNS name www.example.com.>, 'rrset': <DNS www.example.com. IN A RRset: [<0.0.0.0>]>, 'expiration': 0000}
```

There was, unfortunately, no raw bytes message of the DNS response.
How can I, possibly using another library, convert the `dns.resolver.Answer`
to a raw bytes object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dns.resolver.Answer` is built upon a received `dns.resolver.Message`, which does have a `to_wire`.

If you look at the end of https://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/dns.resolver-pysrc.html#Resolver.query you can see how the `Answer` object is computed from the `Message`. But looking at its `init` in https://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/dns.resolver-pysrc.html#Answer.__init__ you can see it keeps the original `Message` (which you need to access the header part of the message, available as flags, etc.)

Hence a quick demonstration would be:

```
In [2]: import dns

In [3]: import dns.resolver

In [4]: ans = dns.resolver.query('www.example.com')

In [5]: print ans
<dns.resolver.Answer object at 0x10b2b0d10>

In [6]: print ans.response
id 21075
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
www.example.com. IN A
;ANSWER
www.example.com. 37157 IN A 93.184.216.34
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL

In [7]: print type(ans.response)
<class 'dns.message.Message'>

In [8]: print ans.response.to_wire()
RS��wwwexamplecom�
                  �%]��"

In [17]: print repr(ans.response.to_wire())
'RS\x81\x80\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03www\x07example\x03com\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\xc0\x0c\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x91%\x00\x04]\xb8\xd8"'

In [18]: r = ans.response.to_wire()

In [19]: message = dns.message.from_wire(r)

In [20]: print message
id 21075
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
www.example.com. IN A
;ANSWER
www.example.com. 37157 IN A 93.184.216.34
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```